# Getting Kendo treeview to work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, treeview, kendo-treeview

So I'm trying to get a simple Kendo treeview to bind to JSON data but I am having a hard time. Any ideas why this isn't working? I put a break point on my JSON result code, but it never even fires.

My HTML:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
                        .Name("treeview")
                        // The property that specifies the text of the node
                        .DataTextField("Name")
                        .LoadOnDemand(true)
                        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                            .Read(read => read
                                // The action method which will return JSON
                                .Action("ReadCats", "Entity")
                                .Data("Id")
                            )
                        )
                    )
```

My Controller:

```
public JsonResult ReadCats(int? id)
{
    var categories = _entityLogic.GetActiveCategories();
    var jsonResult = categories.Select(cat => new
            {
                Id = cat.Id,
                Name = cat.Name,
                HasChildren = categories.Where(c => c.ParentCategory == cat.Id).Any(),
                ParentId = cat.ParentCategory
            }).ToList();
    return Json(jsonResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now if I browse to `myapplication/Admin/Entity/ReadCats`, I do get the JSON data back. Like I said though, the breakpoint never hits when I load the view the tree is on.

Any ideas? I'd note that I've tried every variation of `.Action("ReadCats", "Entity")` I can think of like: `.Action("ReadCats", "/Admin/Entity")`, `.Action("ReadCats", "~/Admin/Entity")`, etc.

Comment: If you use Chrome's F12 dev tools, perhaps you can add a break point on the front end. And also have you tried the Fiddler dev app to call directly into your controller ?